# get checkbox element

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm making a checkbox where every user presses the checkbox, then the contents of the checkbox will appear in the list section  :
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDdCP.png)

the problem is the checkbox that works is only the first checkbox in the list and every time the user presses the checkbox, the content that shown in the list is only the last data in the database.
here is my code :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
                                    <ol class="list-group" >
                                            <div class="card">
                                            <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                <input onclick="checkBox(this)" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver">
                                                    <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                        <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-8">
                                                    <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                                    <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </input>
                                            </li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ol>
                                    @endforeach
```

Here is the code that shows the selected checkbox content :

```
<ol id="list" class="list-group" style="display:none">
                            <div class="card">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                            <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-8">
                                        <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                </div>
                            </ol>
```

and here is the javascript code :

```
<script>
    
function checkBox(){
    // console.log(e)
    var cb = document.getElementById("approver");
    var text = document.getElementById("list");
    if(cb.checked==true){
        text.style.display="block";
    } else {
        text.style.display="none";
    }
}

</script>
```

any solutions?

Comment: Id's should be unique. Switch to a class rather than an id

Comment: do you meant changing the id to class in the javascript?

Comment: you need to change all code

Comment: Voting to close as a typo caused issue. The major issue is that as already commented the id's are not unique in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the passed reference to the checkbox instead of using getElementById as it gets the first occurrence for an element with the provided id, for more details please check [Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

You JS code could be like this:

```
<script>

function checkBox(cb){
    // console.log(e)
    var text = document.getElementById("list");
    if(cb.checked==true){
        text.style.display="block";
    } else {
        text.style.display="none";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: this works to display the card when every checkbox is clicked, but the value appeares is still the last data in the database and only 1 card appears when all checkboxes are clicked

Comment: I think you need to think about changing your code as Nya suggested, you should think about the data in addition to the corresponding UI elements.